# Congruence Proof, sequence is eventually constant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove the notes I find online for my own study in number theory. A topic I didn't do when I was in school. Now I work as a math teacher, trying to learn something new. The question is:

Show that, for any fixed integer $n\geq1$, the sequence

$$2,2^{2},2^{2^{2}},2^{2^{2^{2}}},...\pmod{n}$$

is eventually constant.

I couldn't even find a generic term for this sequence. Let alone prove by induction. Seems this is a recursive relation where $F(n+1)=F(n)^2$. Anyone gives a hint?

Comment: I thought the recursive relation is $F(n+1) = 2^{F(n)}$?

Comment: This does not seem to work modulo $23$, I get the sequence:

$$2,4,16,9,6,18,13,4$$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout WolframAlpha says [$F(6) \equiv 2^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}} \equiv 6\pmod {23}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B2%2CPower%5B2%2CPower%5B2%2CPower%5B2%2CPower%5B2%2C2%5D%5D%5D%5D%5Dmod+23).